# Array related question, cant find the pattern

Tags: arrays

I have to write a c code where for input 4 the output will be
444 4 444
433 3 334
432 2 234
433 3 334
444 4 444

if the input is 2
the
222
212
222

plz help me in that case , I have found the pattern but cant able to execute

plz give me a direction